# Why am I finding the longest increasing subsequence instead of the longest decreasing subsequence?

Tags: python, algorithm, subsequence

I'm trying to look for the longest decreasing subsequence in an array in O(nlogn). Not sure whether this really takes O(nlogn), but anyways this returns the length of the longest increasing subsequence instead of the longest decreasing subsequence. Can anyone help?!?

```
def binary_search(L, l, r, key): 
    while (r - l > 1): 
        m = l + (r - l)//2
        if (L[m] >= key): 
            r = m 
        else: 
            l = m 
    return r 

def LongestDecreasingSubsequenceLength(L, size): 
    tailTable = [0 for i in range(size + 1)] 
    len = 0 
    tailTable[0] = L[0] 
    len = 1
    for i in range(1, size): 
        if (L[i] < tailTable[0]): 
            # new smallest value 
            tailTable[0] = L[i] 
        elif (L[i] > tailTable[len-1]): 
            tailTable[len] = L[i] 
            len+= 1
        else: 
            tailTable[binary_search(tailTable, -1, len-1, L[i])] = L[i]
    return len

L = [ 38, 20, 15, 30, 90, 14, 6, 7] 
n = len(L) 


print("Length of Longest Decreasing Subsequence is ", 
   LongestDecreasingSubsequenceLength(L, n))
```

Comment: I don't understand the "the longest decreasing subsequence" ? Wouldn't going through the list once, and increasing if the next is smaller, and storing if the next is bigger be simpler ?

Comment: In most of the case, this means that some tests are in the wrong order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to any way of looking at it, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) has some pseudocode which transferred easily into Python and flipped for decreasing subsequence.

```
N = len(X)
P = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.int)
M =  np.zeros(N+1, dtype=np.int)

L = 0
for i in range(0, N-1):
    # Binary search for the largest positive j ≤ L
    # such that X[M[j]] <= X[i]
    lo = 1
    hi = L
    while lo <= hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2

        if X[M[mid]] >= X[i]:
            lo = mid+1
        else:
            hi = mid-1
    # After searching, lo is 1 greater than the
    # length of the longest prefix of X[i]
    newL = lo

    # The predecessor of X[i] is the last index of 
    # the subsequence of length newL-1
    P[i] = M[newL-1]
    M[newL] = i
    #print(i)
    if newL > L:
        # If we found a subsequence longer than any we've
        # found yet, update L
        L = newL

# Reconstruct the longest increasing subsequence
S = np.zeros(L, dtype=np.int)
k = M[L]
for i in range(L-1, -1, -1):
    S[i] = X[k]
    k = P[k]

S
```

Which gives the sequence you are after

```
array([38, 20, 15, 14,  6])
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct either... You can clearly see that the longest decreasing subsequence is 5 (38, 20, 15, 14, 6)

Comment: Ah ok, wasn't clear that was what you wanted. Can you update your question with that expected result, and a bit more of the reasoning behind why doing this? This is if you are after the longest decreasing _consecutive_ sequence